# Как изменить Z-index с задержкой в 5сек?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Требуется поменять у данного блока z-index через определенный промежуток времени. Почему мой вариант не работает ? Как реализовать правильнее?

```
export default function(){
    const timerRef = useRef(null);

    const changeIndex = () => {
        const style = {zIndex:30000}
        timerRef.current = setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(styles)
        },1000)
    }



    return(       
            <header className={styles.header + " navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light sticky-top " } style = {{changeIndex}}></header>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю стили не могут быть равны функции, туда нужно передавать объект. А для таймера лучше использовать хук `useEffect`.

```
export default function App() {
  const [headerStyles, setHeaderStyles] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setHeaderStyles({zIndex:30000})
    }, 1000)
  }, [])

  return(       
      <header 
      className={`${styles.header} navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light sticky-top`} 
      style={headerStyles}>
      </header>
  )
}
```